# Mqtt in production

Tags: mqtt, security, esp8266, mosquitto, tls

I am using Mqtt to build a project. I am wanting to move my whole work to prod ready.
My hardware is ESP-07 and custom PCB design the broker is mosquitto the app (Nodejs,react native)

- I implemented Mqtt over TLS and used Let's encrypt certificate.
- I used smart-config and added a layer of encryption[DTLS] to it for
  secure password broadcast.

I am struggling to make an infrastructure so that many of users can use my device on same broker without having access to other people devices. I know access control but I am asking if there an automation plugin

Is there any other elements I should be aware of to launch my product to the market ?

Comment: are you saying that the ESP-07 runs the MQTT broker software?

Comment: of course not the mqtt broker is on separate server

Comment: then, are you asking about the MQTT broker security?

Comment: I am asking for both security, the  client and broker communication and other best practices for mqtt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HiveMQ might be one of possible production ready MQTT brokers. And they also have a community edition but may have some limitations.

Comment: I am asking about elements that I lack in my system, I already have a broker that works. thanks anyways

Comment: They also have a security extension to configure users and permissions. The extension is using a Postgres db. https://www.hivemq.com/docs/ese/4.13/enterprise-security-extension/ese-getting-started.html#getting-started-with-sql-databases